# Lazy Image loading w/ caching

Tags: ios

I am not able to form question title because this question is like descriptive.But I can explain clearly here.This is related to image cache in ios.

**My requirement : I want to create one list which contain Image view and that image loaded from online. Also i need to implement cache for that image (because every time if i loaded fom online it will take too much time and also network consuming).**

**Note: Generally we are preparing cache key for that image based on that image link.**

**Is there any other way to prepare cache key ?**

After loading listview i can click on any row and i will redirect to details page. In that detailed page i have edit option and i can change that image. And i resubmit to server. Once I complete uploading i force close my application and i open as fresh app. In this case in server side no change in **image link because that image link like http://www.uigarden.net/english/images/108.jpg**

Now i load that tableview than and all images frying to load from either cache or server.
So we have two cases.

1) From cache:
    If there is no changing in link and that link id is available in cache folder than it will load from cache. Here
Mu issue : I can not able to find wether it is already edited or not edited. So i can not able to load newly edited image, because i already cached that image based on link.

2) From direct link if that link based key not available in cache .

**How can we distinguish wether it is edit image or old image ?**

please help me

Comment: [Last-Modified](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) and of course add expiration age for the cache.

Answer (score 1):

AFNetWorking in combo with NSURLCache is great

Answer (score 1):

Solution is 
 - [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

You just need to `#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>` to your project, and you can define also the placeholder when image is being downloaded with just this code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        static NSString *CellIdentifier;
        CustomCell *cell = [tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        MyObject *object = (MyObject *)[self.list.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
                       placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

        return cell;
}
```

It also cache downloaded images and gives you great performance.